# Is there a way to show "comic bubbles" with arrows in Qt?

Tags: qt, qt6, qtwidgets

I am looking for a way to show "comic bubbles" pointing to widgets in Qt6 (QtWidgets/C++)? I would like to show something similar to what is in this picture when a help button is pressed (of course only within the window):
[image]
https://sites.google.com/a/simplifiedlogic.com/nitro-cell-v5/nitro-cell-users-guide/graphical-user-interface-gui

**Alternatively:** what is a good, Qt-honic way of onboarding a user to an app on the first run?

Comment: Maybe this example will help? https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtwidgets-painting-painterpaths-example.html